# Finding at a distance from the Earth speed of satellite

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

A satellite at 8000 km from Earth where gravity is 6.4 m/s^2. What is the velocity of satellite? I don't the formula to find speed of satellite.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of any object on an orbit is calculated using this equation:
$$
v=\sqrt{G\frac{M}{r}}
$$
Where $v$ is velocity, $G$ is gravitational constant, $M$ is mass or earth and $r$ is radius of earth plus distance of satelite from earth. if an object is on elliptic orbit the equation is:
$$
v=\sqrt{GM\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)}
$$
Where $a$ is [semi-major axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_axis) of the elliptical orbit.

And remember, you have to know that $g$ (gravitational acceleration) is
$$
g=G\frac{M}{r^2}
$$